# Can someone explain to me about reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I don't understand how to get Reputation. I have tried searching for the answer, but to no avail. Even a link to the correct page will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Give the [FAQ (frequently asked questions)](https://superuser.com/faq#reputation) a read.

There is a whole section explaining what reputation is, how to earn it, and earning it enables you to do.

> The primary way to gain reputation is by posting good questions and useful answers. Your peers will vote on your posts, and those votes will cause you to gain (or, in rare cases, lose) reputation:

Comment: I did that before asking this question, thank you. This does **not** tell you **how** to earn it!

Comment: Indeed it does tell you how to earn it. See the quote @random added - you earn reputation by posting good questions and useful answers. You can also earn rep by accepting answers, and suggesting constructive edits to other people's posts if they get approved.